# Filtering data into a new page in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have some data filtering currently into a list page (master) from a REST API, which includes a mixture of data. I wish to filter the data
into a new page so only data from the category "Watch" is displayed and pulled from the API.

I figure I can do this in 3 ways:

1) Create a filter function on the providers page and use this on watches.ts
2) Create a pipe with the apple_cat/Watch category as a filter
3) Use a structured API call such as https://sheetsu.com/apis/v1.0/d0b1d8ecfc4f/apple_cat/Watch and load that into the page

I have viewed a tutorial that looks to almost get there at https://www.joshmorony.com/filtering-mapping-and-reducing-arrays-in-ionic-2/, but that is using filtering on the same page and not feeding into a new page.

A quick example of the master/detail https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ArIuPt8mKRVFNkWWJfT1JhLUE/view

The Github repo for this Master/Detail setup is here: https://github.com/jones98/Ion2Blank

So just a bit stumped at the correct way to proceed, as I would like quite a few pages with different filtered data.

Here is what i have so far for sheetsu.ts provider file (then change my function on master.html too):

```
// JSON parse and stringify are used so that a new array is created, rather than reference to the original array
this.modifiedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.sheetsuData));

resetData(){
  this.modifiedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.sheetsuData));
}

watchData(){
  this.modifiedData = this.modifiedData.filter((watch) => {
      return watch.apple_cat = Watch;
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you filter data?

Comment: Nothing filtering at present, the list (master) is just a dump of the entire product array.